# Codeigniter 3: send account activation email fails

Tags: arguments, phpmailer, html-email, codeigniter-3

I am working on a *Register and Login* application with CodeIgniter 3 and Twitter Bootstrap.

When a user **[registers](http://code-love.tk/ciauth/)**, an email should be send to the address he/she provided, with an account *confirmation link*. The problem is that the confirmation email **does not send**.

In the **Usermodel** I have:

```
public function activationEmail($first_name='', $last_name='', $email='', $verification_key='')
{
    $this->load->library('email');
    $config = Array(
        'protocol' => 'smtp',
        'smtp_host' => 'smtp.code-love.tk',
        'smtp_port' => 465,
        'smtp_user' => 'razvan@code-love.tk',
        'smtp_pass' => '******',
        'smtp_crypto' => 'ssl',
        'mailtype'  => 'html', 
        'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1'
    );

    $messg = 'Wellcome, '. $first_name . ' ' . $last_name . '! Click the <strong><a href="'.site_url('/signin/activateaccount/'. $verification_key).'">confirmation link</a></strong> to confirm your account.';


    $this->email->initialize($config); 
    $this->email->set_newline('\r\n');
    $this->email->from('mail.code-love.tk','Razvan Zamfir'); 
    $this->email->to($email);
    $this->email->subject('Account activation');
    $this->email->message($messg);
     if (!$this->email->send()) {
    show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
}
  else {
    echo 'Your e-mail has been sent!';
  }
}
```

In my **Signup controller** I have this code:

```
public function signup() {
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('first_name', 'First name', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('last_name', 'Last name', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|trim|valid_email');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|min_length[6]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('cpassword', 'Confirm password', 'required|matches[password]');
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p class="error">', '</p>');

    if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
        $first_name = $this->input->post('first_name');
        $last_name = $this->input->post('last_name'); 
        $email =  $this->input->post('email');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');
        $verification_key = md5($email);
        $date_created = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $date_updated = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $active = 0;
        // Load user model
        $this->load->model('Usermodel');

        // If email does not already exist in the database 
        // signup new user
        if (!$this->Usermodel->email_exists($email)) {
            if ($this->Usermodel->user_register($first_name, $last_name, $email, $password, $verification_key, $date_created, $date_updated, $active) && $this->Usermodel->activationEmail($first_name, $last_name, $email, $verification_key)) {

                $this->session->set_flashdata("signup_success", "Your account has just bean created. You must confirm it before you can sign in. We have send you a confirmation email at $email for this purpose.");

            } else {
                // unless sigup does not fail for whatever reason
                $this->session->set_flashdata("signup_failure", "We ware unable to create your account.");
            }
            redirect('signup'); 
        } else {
            // If email is already in the database
            // urge user to sign in (redirect to signup page too)
            $this->session->set_flashdata("email_exists", "The email address $email already exists in the database. Please signin.");
            redirect('signin'); 
        }
    } else {
        $this->load->view('signup');
    }
}
```

The sign up *does* happen, with the *error below*, and the verification email is not send. I am not doing this from a local XAMPP/WAMP/MAMP server, but from a "live" one, you can **[signup yourself](http://code-love.tk/ciauth/)**.

```
Severity: Warning

Message: fsockopen(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known

Filename: libraries/Email.php
Line Number: 1950

Backtrace:
File: /home/roxoqdat/code-love.tk/ciauth/application/models/Usermodel.php
Line: 52
Function: send

File: /home/roxoqdat/code-love.tk/ciauth/application/controllers/Signup.php
Line: 42
Function: activationEmail

File: /home/roxoqdat/code-love.tk/ciauth/index.php
Line: 292
Function: require_once
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please debug  after the send  and see what error it is showing.                                        
                      echo $this->email->print_debugger();

Comment: Where shall place `echo $this->email->print_debugger();`?

Comment: $this->email->set_mailtype('html');
 $x= $this->email->send(); echo $this->email->print_debugger(); return $x;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you have the required SMTP service.
Try with google SMTP service.

```
    $config = Array(
    'protocol' => 'smtp',
    'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
    'smtp_port' => 465,
    'smtp_user' => 'xxx',
    'smtp_pass' => 'xxx',
    'mailtype'  => 'html', 
    'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1'
);
$this->load->library('email', $config);
$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

$this->email->from('mygmail@gmail.com', 'myname');
$this->email->to('target@gmail.com'); 

$this->email->subject('Email Test');
$this->email->message('Testing the email class.');  


$result = $this->email->send();
```

Next try with:

```
  $config = array('mailtype' => 'html');
```

Remove the rest from $config = array.

Comment: What shall I use as `smtp_user` and `smtp_pass`. And where shall I host the application in this case?

Comment: You can host the application where ever you want. Follow this tutorial on
 How To Use Google's SMTP Server https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-google-s-smtp-server

Comment: SMTP username: Your full Gmail or Google Apps email address (e.g. example@gmail.com or example@yourdomain.com)
SMTP password: Your Gmail or Google Apps email password

Comment: Is it `'protocol' => 'smtp',` or `'protocol' => 'mail',`?

Comment: Simple Mail Transfer Protocol 'protocol' => 'smtp'

Comment: What if I do *not* have SSL on my server?

Comment: smtp and ssl are not the same.. On some hosts you have no need to set these settings, server manages it automatically..  Try sending a mail with only 'mailtype'..    $config = array('mailtype' => 'html');

Comment: SMTP is a protocol for a mail how to be sent SSL stands for Secure Sockets Layer. It is a protocol which creates a secure connection between a client and the server over which to send information.

Comment: No errors and the accounts are created. Only the activation email is not sent.

Comment: What hav you set as target mail? a email adress or variable? sett the $this->email->to('your   target@gmail.com');  and see if you gett any ressault

Answer (score 0):

First of all, after setting flashdata, I don't see you redirecting the user to where they can see it...

Also, send the mail first, then you  set flash data as `An Activation Link Has Been Sent To Your Email, Please Check Your Email To Activate Your Account`!
So,
User Registers,
An email is sent to them only if it doesn't exist already,
Set flashdata for any errors that may arise... Eg:

Assign a variable to the email sending function:

`$send_email = $this->activationEmail('params');`

In your `activationEmail` function, make sure there is a simple control structure like this:

`$success=$this->email->send();`

`if($success){ return true; } else{ return false; }`

Now in your controller, compare to see if mail is actually sent:
`if($send_email == true){ $this->session->flashdata('success','Your success message');`

`// use the redirect() helper function to the function that loads your view`

`} else { //set failed flashdata and redirect to where you want it seen like above}`

You then will know where the problem is.
Let the program flow in your mind first, then implement it. Try that first and get back to me right after.
Hope it somehow helps

Answer (score 0):

Debug whether your parameters are passing or not (specially last_name). Try to write the model method like this to avoid showing errors

```
public function activationEmail($first_name='', $last_name='', $email='', $verification_key='')
```

Try adding header to your email (You are setting mailtype twice, might be an issue).

```
$this->email->set_header('MIME-Version', '1.0; charset=utf-8');
$this->email->set_header('Content-type', 'text/html');
```